# express.js: how to stop in-memory caching for development?

Tags: caching, express

Is there a way to stop express.js from caching static files in memory? Obviously this is just for development, so I don't have to keep restarting the server every time I make a change to an HTML or CSS file. I have looked around and I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Can you share some relevant code? Are you just using `express.static()` middleware, or is there anything else relevant?

Comment: The static content is served by this line:
`app.use(express.static('app')); // serve static content from ./app`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the supervisor module, which can automatically restart the server when files change. To start my server for development, I use `supervisor -e js,css,html server.js` which restarts the server whenever a file with the extension .js, .css, or .html changes (in the current directory or subdirectories).